# T-SQL 2008- Exit when Value is NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isnull, raiserror

I am looking for a way to exit an T-SQL script when @Value is null. This is what I have so far but it does not work as expected:

```
SELECT 
    @Value,
    CASE 
       WHEN @Value IS NULL   
          RAISERROR('EXIT', 16, 1) 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    name LIKE 'test'
```

Comment: `CASE` is used when a decision is made inside a non-imperative context (e.g. inside a `SELECT`). `IF` is used inside a procedural context, such as a T-SQL Batch outside of a query or DDL statement.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that ultimately returns a single, atomic value (an `INT`, a `VARCHAR`) - but it **CANNOT** be used to do program flow control - you need to use `IF`,  `ELSE` etc. for that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
DECLARE @Value INT = 1
IF( @Value IS NULL)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Exit',16,1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Value
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF @Value IS NULL RAISERROR('EXIT', 16,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a cursor and a temp table you can get the output you want. don't know if that's the goal,

```
USE AdventureWorksLT2012

DECLARE @CustomerID AS INT
DECLARE @CompanyName AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @EmailAddress AS VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #output (CustomerID INT,CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX),EmailAddress VARCHAR(MAX)) 

DECLARE testCursor CURSOR 
    FOR 
    SELECT TOP (100) 
       CustomerID
      ,CompanyName
      ,EmailAddress
    FROM SalesLT.Customer   
    ORDER BY customerID DESC;

OPEN testCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM testCursor
INTO @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @emailAddress;
if @EmailAddress is not null
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #output values( @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @emailAddress);  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
     BEGIN  
        FETCH NEXT FROM testCursor
        INTO @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @emailAddress;
        if @EmailAddress is null 
        BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Exit',16,1);
          BREAK;
        end
        INSERT INTO #output values( @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @emailAddress);
       END;
    END
CLOSE testCursor;
DEALLOCATE testCursor;

SELECT * FROM #output;

DROP TABLE #output
```